# WebAPI 2 Configuração de Rotas aplicação web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Faz uns 6 meses que estou entrando no mundo MVC, antes utilizei muito WebForms e confesso que estou com dificuldades de entender como configurar as rotas  para um **`ApiController`**, pelo que notei não posso ter duas consultas iguais (com os mesmos parâmetros), mas estou um pouco atrapalhado para configurar isso.

Abaixo vou colocar um exemplo de código que esta dando o erro abaixo ao tentar acessá-los.

```
{  
   "Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:54596/api/graficos/usuarios/'.",
   "MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Graficos' that matches the name 'usuarios'."
}
```

**GraficosController**

```
public class GraficosController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    //[Route("api/graficos/usuarios/{action}/{param}")]
    public List<UsuarioDashboard> BuscaUsuarioDashboard(string param)
    {
        return Fachada.FachadaEstatisticas.BuscaUsuarioDashboard(param);
    }
    [HttpGet]
    //[Route("api/graficos/emails/{action}/{param}")]
    public List<EmailNaoEnviado> EmailsNaoEnviados(string data)
    {
        return Fachada.FachadaEstatisticas.EmailsNaoEnviados(Convert.ToDateTime(data));
    }

}
```

No **Global.asax** estou fazendo a rota da seguinte maneira:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Site",
    routeTemplate: "api/{Controller}/{action}/{site}",
    defaults: new { }
);

 RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "Usuarios",
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{param}",
     defaults: new { }
 );

 RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "Graficos",
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
     defaults: new { }
 );
```

Creio que meu erro seja tentar aproveitar o mesmo controller para mais de uma função. Será isso?

Já pesquisei em vários sites, mas não achei nenhum que tenha uma explicação que eu entenda.

Comment: Por que você não usa atributos por rotas?

Comment: e como seria? ja tentei muita coisa...

Comment: Isto do jeito que está não vai funcionar. O que é `RouteTable`?

Comment: @AlexBecker Isso é pra ser uma aplicação WebForms?

Comment: Não preciso configurar as rotas no Global.asax? posso colocar decorando o parametro direto no controller como eu comentei no código acima?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex, primeiro que você não precisa registrar varias rotas no seu `Global.asax`, s você precisa personalizar uma rota usando o atributo `Route`.

Sei que já fez boa parte do trabalho abaixo, mas só por garantia irei começar do começo.:

Crie uma classe `WebApiConfig` dentro de `App_Start`:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

No `global.asax` realize apenas o registro das rotas:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);          
}
```

agora nas suas classes, faça assim:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/graficos")]
public class GraficosController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("BuscaUsuarioDashboard/{param}")]
    public List<UsuarioDashboard> BuscaUsuarioDashboard(string param)
    {
        return Fachada.FachadaEstatisticas.BuscaUsuarioDashboard(param);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("EmailsNaoEnviados/{data}")]
    public List<EmailNaoEnviado> EmailsNaoEnviados(string data)
    {
        return Fachada.FachadaEstatisticas.EmailsNaoEnviados(Convert.ToDateTime(data));
    }
}
```

agora você poderá fazer as seguintes chamadas:

```
GET: api/graficos/EmailsNaoEnviados/2016-01-01
GET: api/graficos/BuscaUsuarioDashboard/userName
```

FONTE: [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: Muito bom isso que eu precisa obrigado, tentei tanta coisa que ja tinha desorganizado meu código... valeu

Comment: @AlexBecker, não deixe de acessar o link que coloquei no final da resposta, talvez lhe ajude a organizar o seu código.